# I cannot untar a zip file keep getting error

Tags: bash, tar, zip, gzip

From the link below I try to follow the steps and I got the curl portion to work but when I type

```
tar zxf admit.tar.gz
```

I get

```
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

I have no idea what to do I double click to unzip but then I have a new file come out as `admit.tar.gz.cpgz`  I am not sure what to do? I am trying to follow the steps provided on website but it does not work.

http://admit.astro.umd.edu/installguide.html

Comment: personally I get a "file not found" page when attempting to download the file. perhaps your file contains this message rather than a well-formed tarball?

Comment: What does `file file.tar.gz` return?

Comment: ADMIT = ALMA Data Mining Toolkit. ........ Get `admit-master.zip` from https://github.com/astroumd/admit .... or download with `git clone https://github.com/astroumd/admit`

Comment: Try gunzip on the original file

Comment: Or just cat it. I get 7 lines of HTML with a 404 message. But it comes to stdout, not to a .tar.gz file. So I assume "I got the curl portion to work" includes a redirection that is not shown in the question. `file` returns `Curl.msg: HTML document, ASCII text` and the file is only 196 bytes: both somewhat informative diagnostics.

Comment: The zip from github  is 12Mb+.

Answer (score 1):

The installation instructions are slightly out of date. These are not compressed as `gz` files but `xz`. For `tar` that means instead of using the `z` flag you need to use `J`. For example to list the farchive contents:

```
tar tJvf file-you-downloaded.xz
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do `strings admit.tar.gz` to see if what you have is a real binary file or an HTTP error message.

Edit: This is basically the same as Paul_Pedant's answer but has the advantage of not messing up your terminal if it *is* a gzipped file!